# Show alert with message after push received. Phonegap

Tags: cordova, push-notification, phonegap-plugins, cordova-2.0.0

I'm using [GitHub-GCM Cordova plugin](https://github.com/marknutter/GCM-Cordova). My problem is that I unable to show push message after I receive it.

GCMIntentService:

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
Log.d(TAG, "onMessage - context: " + context);

Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
//show alert
}
//...
}
```

I should be java code I think, because I have no idea how to refer to html/js.. But AlertDialog Builder doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can show alert after receiving push with this code:

```
String message = extras.getString("message");
String title = extras.getString("title");
Notification notif = new Notification(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on, message, System.currentTimeMillis() );
notif.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notif.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
notif.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, TestSampleApp.class);
notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, contentIntent);
String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(ns);
mNotificationManager.notify(1, notif);
```

Put it where it receive the push.

Comment: Thanks, I already found it in tutorials, but I'm trying to make it in other way - alertdialog.